# how to use the formatVideoToWebpSticker function in whatsapp web js

Tags: javascript, mp4, whatsapp, webp, whatsapp-stickers

I'm trying to figure out how to use this to convert a video to a webp file.
I took this code from the Util file from the documentation.
I'm doing this because I figured it takes 5 seconds to send a video using whatsapp web js and sending a webp will be faster

the code:

```
     * Formats a video to webp
     * @param {MessageMedia} media
     * 
     * @returns {Promise&lt;MessageMedia>} media in webp format
     */
    static async formatVideoToWebpSticker(media) {
        if (!media.mimetype.includes('video'))
            throw new Error('media is not a video');
        const videoType = media.mimetype.split('/')[1];
        const tempFile = path.join(
            tmpdir(),
            `${Crypto.randomBytes(6).readUIntLE(0, 6).toString(36)}.webp`
        );
        const stream = new (require('stream').Readable)();
        const buffer = Buffer.from(
            media.data.replace(`data:${media.mimetype};base64,`, ''),
            'base64'
        );
        stream.push(buffer);
        stream.push(null);
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ffmpeg(stream)
                .inputFormat(videoType)
                .on('error', reject)
                .on('end', () => resolve(true))
                .addOutputOptions([
                    '-vcodec',
                    'libwebp',
                    '-vf',
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
                    'scale=\'iw*min(300/iw\,300/ih)\':\'ih*min(300/iw\,300/ih)\',format=rgba,pad=300:300:\'(300-iw)/2\':\'(300-ih)/2\':\'#00000000\',setsar=1,fps=10',
                    '-loop',
                    '0',
                    '-ss',
                    '00:00:00.0',
                    '-t',
                    '00:00:05.0',
                    '-preset',
                    'default',
                    '-an',
                    '-vsync',
                    '0',
                    '-s',
                    '512:512',
                ])
                .toFormat('webp')
                .save(tempFile);
        });
        const data = await fs.readFile(tempFile, 'base64');
        await fs.unlink(tempFile);
        return {
            mimetype: 'image/webp',
            data: data,
            filename: media.filename,
        };
    }
```